# jQuery 3.x .off() after .on()

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-3

I simply used .off() method after .on() method for .click() method.
I'm really confused why click() event fires!

```js
$('span').on('click', function () { $('p').text("You Clicked!") });

$('span').off('click', function () { 
  $('p').text("Ha Ha Ha!") });
```

```css
span{
  background-color:#ac0;
  padding:5px;
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span>Click Me!</span>
<p>*****</p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've misunderstood what the function is for at the end of the `off()` method. It isn't a callback, it's an event handler.

That function is supposed to be the same event handler function as the one you set initially. This is done this way so that you can remove an individual click handler.

```
function handlerA(e) {
  console.log('heard by A');
}

function handlerB(e) {
  console.log('heard by B');
}

// add both handlers to click events
$('span').on('click', handlerA);
$('span').on('click', handlerB);

// remove the first click event only, leaving the second
$('span').off('click', handlerA);
```

The above would only log `heard by B` when clicked.

To remove *all* click handlers, you need to omit the function entirely.

```
$('span').off('click');
```

Comment: @SalmanShariati don't forget to mark one of the answers correct

Answer (score 3):

You're trying to remove a *different* handler function than was originally assigned.

Instead, create a reference to the function and add/remove it by that reference:

```
var clickHandler = function () { $('p').text("You Clicked!") };

$('span').on('click', clickHandler);
$('span').off('click', clickHandler);
```